# Angular E2E testing with mocked httpBackend?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

A hot discussion raised between me and my boss about [Angular E2E testing.](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing) according to [vojitajina pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/pull/28) we need to run a server in order to run the e2e tests. So, running e2e test involves a real server, a real server involves DB. This makes test slow.Ok, now the question is how to test e2e without involving a real server ? is there a way to use httpBackend to and the e2e angular API where I can use browser(), element(), select(), for my tests ?

Answer (score 5):

[see edit below] We use a shell script to periodically capture curl requests from our seeded test server. These responses are then returned via $httpBackend.whenGet(...).respond() to intercept and return that data.

So, in our index.html

```
if (document.location.hash === '#test') {
  addScript('/test/lib/angular-mocks.js');
  addScript('/test/e2e/ourTest.js');
  window.fixtures = {};
  addScript('/test/fixtures/tasks/tasks_p1.js');
  // the tasks_p1.js is generated and has "window.fixtures.tasks_p1 = ...json..."
  addScript('/test/fixtures/tasks/tasks_p2.js');
  // the tasks_p2.js is generated and has "window.fixtures.tasks_p2 = ...json..."
  addScript('/test/e2e/tasks/taskMocks.js\'><\/script>');
}
```

ourTest.js

```
angular.module('ourTestApp', ['ngMockE2E','taskMocks']).
    run(function ($httpBackend, taskMocks) {
      $httpBackend.whenGET(/views\/.*/).passThrough();
      $httpBackend.whenGET(/\/fixtures.*\//).passThrough();

      taskMocks.register();

      $httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/).passThrough();
    });
```

taskMocks.js

```
/*global angular */
angular.module('taskMocks', ['ngMockE2E']).
  factory('taskMocks', ['$httpBackend', function($httpBackend) {
  'use strict';
  return {
    register: function() {
      $httpBackend.whenGET(..regex_for_url_for_page1..).respond(window.fixtures.tasks_p1);
      $httpBackend.whenGET(..regex_for_url_for_page2..).respond(window.fixtures.tasks_p2);
    }
  };
}]);
```

In a few cases our data is related to the current date; e.g. "tasks for this week", so we massage the captured data in the register() method.

**EDIT**
We now use [Rosie](https://github.com/bkeepers/rosie) to create factories for our mocked objects. So, no more CURLing test server for expected json responses. index.html no longer loads these ".js" fixtures and the mocks look like:

taskMocks.js

```
/*global angular */
angular.module('taskMocks', ['ngMockE2E']).
  factory('taskMocks', ['$httpBackend', function($httpBackend) {
  'use strict';
  var tasks_p1 = [ Factory.build('task'), Factory.build('task')], 
      tasks_p2 = [ Factory.build('task'), Factory.build('task')] 
  return {
    register: function() {
      $httpBackend.whenGET(..regex_for_url_for_page1..).respond(tasks_p1);
      $httpBackend.whenGET(..regex_for_url_for_page2..).respond(tasks_p2);
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Sorry but, I did not understand anything.

Comment: What is "curl requests" and what do you mean by seeded test server ?

Comment: Sorry - tried to give you enough to get you over the hump. curl is a command line tool for making a web request.

Comment: will this setup work with karma? Also, is "ourTestApp" the name of your app or separate app for testing like the answer below?

Comment: @wakandan it works w/ karma and 'ourTestApp' is name of our separate testing app module.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question, yes there is a way to do it without involving a real server and you can use $httpBackend to mock responses in e2e tests, but it is not as straightforward as with mocking them in the unit tests. You also need to include angular-mocks.js in the index.html as well as 'ngMockE2E' in app.js.

[How to mock an AJAX request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899176/how-to-mock-an-ajax-request/17969366#17969366)

Comment: If you're going to downvote, please comment as to why. The question was "how to test e2e without involving a real server ? is there a way to use httpBackend to and the e2e angular API where I can use browser(), element(), select(), for my tests ?" and I believe I have answered that!

Comment: this is how I do it and it works - so it's an upvote from me