# How to mock an ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, mocking

How can one mock an ajax response?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13915248/1032531 provides a link to an answer but the link is broken.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29680013/1032531 provides the following answer but it errors with `$.ajax is not a function`.  https://jsfiddle.net/bdw0gfan/

```
 function ajax_response(response) {
   var deferred = $.Deferred().resolve(response);
   return deferred.promise();
 }
 $(function() {

   $.ajax = ajax_response([1, 2, 3]);
   $.ajax('GET', 'some/url/i/fancy').done(function(data) {
     console.log(data); // [1, 2, 3]
   });
 });
```

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src/ajax

Comment: BTW, you should make `ajax_response` return a function tht will act as `$.ajax`: `function ajax_response(response) { return function() { var deferred... } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.ajax` needs to be a function or else it won't return the promise.

```js
function ajax_response(response) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred().resolve(response);
    return deferred.promise();
}

$.ajax = function() {
    return ajax_response([1, 2, 3]); 
};

$.ajax('GET', 'some/url/i/fancy').done(function(data) {
    console.log(data); // [1, 2, 3]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks

Comment: Probably make `ajax_response` return a function, that way you don't need to manually redefine `$.ajax` each time you want to mock it with a different response.